# Dividir 2 array, y determinar el resultado en un tercer arreglo

Tags: php

estoy iniciando en el PHP ¡¡
Estoy intentando dividir 2 arreglos y obtener el resultado en un tercer arreglo, pero me aparece
Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError.
Muchas Gracias ¡¡¡
el código es:

```
<?php
$visitas = array(4, 5, 8, 9, 10);
$ventas = array(2, 4, 5, 6, 1);
if (($visitas > 0) && ($ventas > 0)) {
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($visitas); $i++) {
    $division[] = $visitas[$i] * $ventas[$i];
}
var_dump($division);
}
?>
```

Comment: Este código está multiplicando, no dividiendo, y este solo tiene un error de ArrayIndex. Estás seguro que este es el código?

De cualquier forma ese error te sale porque estás intentando dividir un número entre 0

Comment: Hay varios fallos, aparte de que no divides sino que multiplicas. El condicional es raro, pues evaluas las variables de array como si fueran números comparándolos con 0, cuando yo lo haria con **count** en ambas variables para saber si tienen elementos o no.  Luego no compruebas si ambas variables tienen el mismo número de elementos, y el `$i=1` hace que te saltes el primero de ellos, debería ser `$i=0`, y esto: `$i <= count($visitas)` debería ser esto: `$i <= count($visitas)-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios fallos, aparte de que no divides sino que multiplicas.

El condicional es raro, pues evaluas las variables de array como si fueran números comparándolos con `0`, cuando yo lo haria con `count` en ambas variables para saber si tienen elementos o no.

Luego no compruebas si ambas variables tienen el mismo número de elementos, y el `$i=1` hace que te saltes el primero de ellos, debería ser `$i=0`, y esto: `$i <= count($visitas)` debería ser esto: `$i <= count($visitas)-1` porque no es lo mismo el número de elementos de un array con sus índices, que empiezan en `0`, no en `1`, por lo tanto tienes que restar `1` a su contaje en el condicional.

Todo esto que he dicho quedaría así:

```php
$visitas = array(4, 5, 8, 9, 10);
$ventas = array(2, 4, 5, 6, 1);
if ((count($visitas) == count($ventas)) and count($visitas) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($visitas)-1; $i++) {
        $division[] = $visitas[$i] / $ventas[$i];
    }
    var_dump($division);
}
```

dando como resultado esto (lo muestro con [print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) que me gusta más):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1.25
    [2] => 1.6
    [3] => 1.5
    [4] => 10
)
```

Y aquí lo muestro con *var_dump* para que veras el tipo de resultados de cada elemento:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  float(1.25)
  [2]=>
  float(1.6)
  [3]=>
  float(1.5)
  [4]=>
  int(10)
}
```

Ya nos dirás si te ha funcionado.